# How to insert billing details into Woocommerce email?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am wondering how could I insert billing details (name, email and phone number) into Woocommerce email?

Here is the code from Woocommerce-appointment plugin I'm using to send emails:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading ); ?>

<?php if ( $appointment->get_order() && $appointment->get_order()->billing_first_name && $appointment->get_order()->billing_last_name ) : ?>
<p><?php printf( $opening_paragraph, $appointment->get_order()->billing_first_name . ' ' . $appointment->get_order()->billing_last_name ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<table>
<tbody>
    <?php if ( $appointment->has_staff() && ( $staff = $appointment->get_staff_member() ) ) : ?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Appointment Provider', 'woocommerce-appointments' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $staff->display_name; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Appointment Date', 'woocommerce-appointments' ); ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $appointment->get_start_date( wc_date_format(), '' ); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Appointment Time', 'woocommerce-appointments' ); ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $appointment->get_start_date( '', get_option( 'time_format' ) ) . ' &mdash; ' . $appointment->get_end_date( '', get_option( 'time_format' ) ); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Appointment Time', 'woocommerce-appointments' ); ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $appointment->get_start_date( '', get_option( 'time_format' ) ) . ' &mdash; ' . $appointment->get_end_date( '', get_option( 'time_format' ) ); ?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer' ); ?>
```

I want to insert name, email and phone into this (example for Customer name):

```
<tr>
<th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Customer Email', 'woocommerce-appointments' ); ?></th>
<td>**HERE**</td>
</tr>
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text );` ? This action hook is basically from `customer-processing-order.php` email template, which by default displays customer information (billing details & shipping details) in email. Though I have not tried using it in any other plugin email template, I guess I would work.

Comment: Have you read this: [**Woocommerce emails - how to add information of billing**](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202285577-Woocommerce-emails-how-to-add-information-of-billing-), a little old but may be interesting…

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the answers. Unfortunately neither worked. But I managed to output the name, email and phone in really simple way:

```
echo $appointment->get_order()->billing_first_name . ' ' . $appointment->get_order()->billing_last_name;
echo $appointment->get_order()->billing_email;
echo $appointment->get_order()->billing_phone;
```